# Resize Window/Application with Command Prompt (command)? - (.bat files)

Tags: batch-file, resize, window, command-prompt, window-resize

Is there a command in command prompt I can use to resize another window by dimensions? I would prefer to make a .bat file that can resize one or two specific applications/programs, but I can't seem to find a way to resize programs through command prompt instead of by dragging the corners of the window.

Also, some .exe's don't allow you to resize the window through the usual method (dragging the corners).
Any suggestions?

Comment: The command prompt is older than GUIs and therefore has no concept of what a window is.

Comment: Is there any other varying way I can resize the window through code?

Comment: Yes there is, use a coding/scripting language which has that ability. You will find the site search facility, or your chosen web search engine useful for making a decision on which to employ.

Comment: See 
https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/2021/03/sizewindowexe-changes-size-of-window.html?m=1

Comment: you can embed a c# code into batch and use platform invoke: https://improve.dk/modifying-window-location-and-size/ . If I have time today I'll try to assemble you a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be helpful but you can resize the command prompt window with

```
mode con: lines=10 cols=20
```